# Can Cycles renders be done from the command line?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, command-line

It seems that Cycles is mainly built in the form of Python scripts (as far as I can tell). Is it still possible to use Cycles to render a `.blend` file from the command line?

Comment: The current tag is actually wrong.. temporarily changed it. It should be command-line with a dash, will retag when it is ok to, the old tags take a while to disappear..

Comment: update, fixed it, the old one has been deleted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes you can, This will render a single frame

```
blender --background filename.blend --render-output //test_ --engine CYCLES --render-format PNG --use-extension 1 --render-frame 5
```

This will output a file named `test_0005`

While experimenting, I more or less substituted `CYCLES` with the parameters I found [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/command_line.html). You can check the link to see what they mean and or do.

Comment: Tip - to list available rendering engines:

 ``blender --background --engine help``

Comment: The --engine switch is almost never necessary, you will have already saved the .blend file with Cycles set as render engine while editing it, and it will use that for rendering from the command line too. And this works for render engines like Luxrender or Yafaray too.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an overview of (near) all command line options for Blender:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/advanced/command_line/render.html

```
blender -b file.blend -o //file -F JPEG -x 1 -f 1
```