# How do I set a specific render engine while launching blender?

Tags: rendering, customization, command-line

I have noticed that Blender Internal Render Engine is the default engine that is set when launching Blender. Users can change this behavior by setting a different engine and saving the user preferences.

My question is, is it possible to choose the engine to be used by blender when launching blender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you figured this out, just note that you can enable addons on startup too:

```
blender --addons my_render_engine --engine MY_RENDER_ENGINE
```

If you want to enable multiple addons...

```
blender --addons my_render_engine,some_other_addon --engine MY_RENDER_ENGINE
```

Where the add-on list is comma separated list of module names (no spaces), the engine argument works as normal.

See [the manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#render-options) for documentation on these args.

Comment: This is a late comment, but thanks for that addon enabling tip.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.

There are lots of command-line flags provided by Blender and the flags that are related to rendering engine type are *-E engine* or *--engine engine*

So, to launch Blender with the CYCLES rendering engine set, the following command can be used.

```
blender --engine CYCLES
```

You can get a list of available engines by using

```
blender --engine help
```

or

```
blender -E help
```

Example output

```
found bundled python: /home/satishg/bin/blender-2.65a-linux-glibc27-x86_64/2.65/python
Blender Engine Listing:
    BLENDER_RENDER
    BLENDER_GAME
    CYCLES

[1]    Done                          ~/bin/blender-2.65a-linux-glibc27-x86_64/blender --engine help
```

Comment: Also see related http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/313/12 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/80/12