# Setting render options from the command line

Tags: rendering, command-line

I was hoping to render blender using the command line mode on linux. However, I do not no how to set the output resolution and H.264 as the encoding. Both these options work in the GUI mode but I wish to use them from the command line

Comment: You can't set the dimensions from the command line. I'm also certain variations of this have been asked before.. please have a look through the [commandline](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) tag.. or specifically [Can Cycles renders be done from the command line?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/80/12) and [Is there a way to batch render multiple scenes?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/313/12). Have a look at the parameters in the second link and I believe you can pass `H.264` to `-F`.

Comment: Modified the question title, since theres nothing specific to H264 about your question (for any other format the answer would be the same).

Comment: pretty neat one: bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'

Comment: Yes, you can set the dimensions from the command line. The `render-batch` script in [this repo](https://github.com/ldo/render-useful) does exactly that.

Comment: I prefer to render to separate PNG frames (or alternatively OpenEXR). Then I encode the frames separately using FFmpeg. This way I can tweak the quality settings etc without having to re-render.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Command line

One way is to set the properties from the gui, save the file, then render. The settings will be preserved for rendering from the command line.

Note that (as already [mentioned by iKlsR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/setting-render-options-from-the-command-line/3062#comment5121_3061)) you can set the render output format from the command line with `-F`:

```
Format Options:
-F or --render-format <format>
Set the render format, Valid options are...
    TGA IRIS JPEG MOVIE IRIZ RAWTGA
    AVIRAW AVIJPEG PNG BMP FRAMESERVER
(formats that can be compiled into blender, not available on all systems)
    HDR TIFF EXR MULTILAYER MPEG AVICODEC QUICKTIME CINEON DPX DDS
```

However, it seems `H264` is not a valid setting for this argument.

Further reading: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options

## Python

Another way is to use [blender's python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/), and run a python script in blender from the command line ([see this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui)), e.g.:

```
blender --background /path/to/file.blend --python /path/to/script.py --render-anim
```

or

```
blender -b /path/to/file.blend -P /path/to/script.py -a
```

The render resolution can be set with [`bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings.resolution_x) and [`bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings.resolution_y).

The output format can be set to H.264 with
[`bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'H264'`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.html#bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.file_format).

#### Note on scene values:

You may want to assign the settings for all scenes to avoid confusion with complex setups which use multiple scenes.

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
    scene.render.resolution_y = 1080
    scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'H264'
```

#### Note invoking render:

When using a Python script to render you have the choice to...

- Pass the `--render-anim` argument.
- Call `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)` directly from the Python script.

Both do the same thing however calling the operator from Python means if the script fails to run, render won't execute, *This may be good/bad depending on your use-case*.

Calling from Python also gives some flexibility - for example you could call render multiple times with different frame ranges.

Comment: Note: to avoid creating a script file just for this, a python expression can be passed directly at the command line (the \n should be replaced with actual newlines): `blender -b path/to/file.blend --python-expr "import bpy\n
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:\n
    scene.render.resolution_x = 1920\n
    scene.render.resolution_y = 1080\n
    scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'H264'" -a`

Comment: instead of /n you can use semicolons ;