# Rendering using CLI

Tags: rendering, command-line

I'm trying to code a webapp similar to http://tarkett-professionals.esignserver3.com/gallery.do but simpler. I've checked blender documentation but being a developer not a modeler/3d artist i couldn't find answer to this.

Is it  possible to render a single frame of a scene using command line interface with given variables like a color of a surface or the camera angle?

Or can you point me to a direction i can achieve this kind of task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Rendering from the CLI is possible](http://blender.org/manual/render/workflows/command_line.html), however to change things like camera angle/materials you'll have to [feed blender a python script](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3061/599) which can make these changes via the [python api](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/).

Comment: @gandalf3 Cheers mate i'll check those links.

Comment: The important thing to note is that with the command line, you can add custom arguments at the end of the cli call. Then in python you can read them back in with sys.argv[i]. The caveat is that you would read them in order of last argument first with sys.argv[-1], sys.argv[-2], etc. That's how you pipe in custom values for your startup python script.