# How to edit blender file parameters + settings from command line or python?

Tags: python, command-line

**Note: This is** *not* a duplicate of this question: [How can I run blender from command line or a python script without opening a GUI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365)

That question only addresses rendering, not modifying parameters in a closed file without a GUI.

I'm currently rendering a Blender scene using Colab.

The problem is that I have to constantly upload a new file to my Google drive with altered settings if I want to alter settings.

Is it possible to alter parameters (such as a parameter in a node like "Density"), and settings like resolution percentage from the command line or from Python by opening the .blend file and reading and writing to it?

I would need to be able to alter the settings not by opening blender but either through the command line or through python.

Comment: Sure. Does this answer your question? [How can I run blender from command line or a python script without opening a GUI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui)

Comment: Also see: [Setting render options from the command line](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/setting-render-options-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Sorry I don't think those don't answer my question because those are about setting minimal things like format, and resolution but I want the ability to modify any parameter at all (such as density of a node, number of samples, etc.) either from the command line or from a python script that's not running inside of a blender GUI.

Comment: Edit: It seems from a comment underneath an answer it might be possible to modify settings in the command line through a python expression. I will look into this, and if I figure something out, I will post a usage example. Sorry about that. I guess I wanted a straightforward usage example

Comment: Updated the answers, Based on the information given in your question, still a dupe IMHO and exactly what you're asking for. As mentioned in *both* Q&A's, you can run a python script: `blender --background --python myscript.py`, an expression, or even the console: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options Suggest to add the current state of your code to your question.