# How to render in command line?

Tags: rendering, command-line

I have a very very slow computer, but would like to animate 3D. I'm aware we can render via the command line. but I don't know how. I want to render the entire animation of my Tutorial.blend file in the background.

Comment: Have you searched for it, because this question already has an answer see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80/can-cycles-renders-be-done-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 10):

Firstly open your Command Processor.

> Windows(**Command Prompt**)
>   Linux(**Terminal**)
>   Mac(**Command Line**).

### For Windows:

In cmd first type `set path="C:\Program Files\Blender 2.80"` replace it with path were your blender is extracted or installed. And press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Now we to locate the folder where you save your Blender files.
So in cmd, type

```
cd yourpath
```

If you didn't get what to type after `cd` than make a folder named Blender Projects on your Desktop and move the .blend files in it, and in cmd type

```
cd desktop\blender projects
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
You are in the expected location,
Now,
If you want to animate,
run
this command,

```
blender -b yourfilename.blend -a
```

### Rendering Single Frames

```
blender -b file.blend -f 10
```

`-f 10` describes which frame you wish to render, in this case single 10th frame will be rendered.

You can also set start frame and end frame for animation just add this block in your **animation** command

```
-s 10 -e 500
```

`-s` refers to start and `-e` refers to end, replace numbers with yours.
You can also refer the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workflows/command_line.html) provided by Blender Foundation.

> Editing is greatly appreciated to this answer for Linux and Mac users.

Hope this information may be helpful. All the best.