# render curve color

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves, color, 2d

I'm a total beginner in blender but this software is so nice.

I'm trying to render a 2d scene wich simply changes material colors and zooms out camera. This should lead to a 2d logo animation. I set everything up with curves imported from inkscape. Everything renders properly. There is only one problem – the saturation is much less than in inkscape.

So here comes my question:
Is there an option to render colors as defined?
E.g. when I define RGB 15,234,124 the output becomes these values?

I'm rendering with cycles render because I wanted to have the material options.

Is there any option to set to make rendering faster for these purposes (it's really slow and I think this action should be easy for blender).

And how to output high quality videos? Only rendering PNGs makes me able to have a high quality video.

Have a nice weekend.

Manuel

Answer (score 1):

> So here Comes my Question: Is there an Option to render Colors as defined? E.g. when I define RGB 15,234,124 the Output becomes These values?

No, because that’s not how light transport works.

Comment: this means there is no Options to achieve Inputs=Output for Colors in blender?

Comment: Imagine putting a colour on a display and then taking a photo of it. The chances that you’d be able to get the exact colour you displayed encoded in a photograph are exactly zero, because every camera has different encoding characteristics. The simple fact is that you could indeed get a perfect 1:1, but the rest of your render would look beyond awful because of the nature of light transport. Rendering is closer to photography than plopping a colour on a screen in MS Paint; it’s quite a sophisticated set of light transport emulations.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any Option to set to make Rendering faster for These purposes
>   (it's really slow and I think These Action should be easy for blender)

Here are some of the settings that might be helpful:

### Reduce samples:

Reducing sample as low as possible will render your scene faster, but it will turn your render noisy, so there's an option for Denoising. There is [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings) asked previously in which it is explained that how we can use Denoising with adjusting no. of Samples and Clamping.This will reduce your render time almost to half.
[image]

### Simplify:

According to the Blender Manual it automatically scales textures down so that they are no larger than the values chosen. This can help reduce computer memory resources when rendering large scenes with huge textures.
[image]

### Use Large tile size:

This will make not more than a slight difference in render times.
[image]

### Using Command line to render:

Using command line is the better way to render, because without opening Blender you can render your Animations, and it is faster because now your CPU/GPU don't have to handle the heavy graphical interface of Blender. If you don't know to do this check out this [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80/can-cycles-renders-be-done-from-the-command-line).

> If you want a detailed tutorial watch [this](https://youtu.be/8gSyEpt4-60) tutorial by Blender
>   Guru.
>
> Speed of rendering not only depends upon what settings you have
>   adopted but also depends on the scene complexity.